# How can I use values stored in an array to another method to do a calculation?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
static void diceRoll(int[] val) {

        for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
            int roll1 = (int) ((Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1));
            int roll2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1));
            int roll3 = (int) ((Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1));
            int roll4 = (int) ((Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1));
             int total =0;
            if ((roll1 < roll2) && (roll1 < roll3) && (roll1 < roll4)) {
                total= roll2 + roll3 + roll4;
            } else if ((roll2 < roll1) && (roll2 < roll3) && (roll2 < roll4)) {
                total= roll1 + roll3 + roll4;
            } else if ((roll3 < roll1) && (roll3 < roll2) && (roll3 < roll4)) {
                total = roll1 + roll2 + roll4;
            } else if ((roll4 < roll1) && (roll4 < roll2) && (roll4 < roll3)) {
                total = roll1 + roll2 + roll3;
            }
        }
}


static void calculateBonus(int[] bonusVal){
    int bonus=0;
    int[] val= new int[6];

    for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++)


        if (val[i] > 10 && val[i] != 11) {
            bonusVal[j] = (val[i] - 10) / 2;
        } else if (val[i] < 10) {
            bonusVal[j] = ((val[i] / 2) - 5);
        } else if (val[i] == 10 || val[i] == 11) {
            bonusVal[j] = 0;
        }
}


public static void main(String[]args){




    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Declaring variables
    int level;
    String choice = null;

    //Getting the Level value
    System.out.println("Enter the Level value :");
    level = sc.nextInt();
    while ((level<=0)||(level>20)){
        System.out.println("Invalid input.Please enter a number between 1-20.");
        System.out.println("Enter the Level value : ");
        level = sc.nextInt();
    }
    do{
        int[] val= new int[6];
        int _str= val[0];
        int con= val[1];
        int dex= val[2];
        int _int= val[3];
        int wis= val[4];
        int _cha= val[5];


        int [] bonusVal=new int[6];
        int bonus1= bonusVal[0];
        int bonus2= bonusVal[1];
        int bonus3= bonusVal[2];
        int bonus4= bonusVal[3];
        int bonus5= bonusVal[4];
        int bonus6= bonusVal[5];


        //Printing the Level
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nLevel :  [ "+level+" ]");

        //Displaying out put
        System.out.println("_Str  :  ["+_str+" ]"+"["+bonus1+"]");
        System.out.println("Dex  :  ["+dex+" ]"+"["+bonus2+"]");
        System.out.println("Con  :  ["+con+" ]"+"["+bonus3+"]");
        System.out.println("Int  :  ["+_int+" ]"+"["+bonus4+"]");
        System.out.println("Wis  :  ["+wis+" ]"+"["+bonus5+"]");
        System.out.println("_Cha  :  ["+_cha+" ]"+"["+bonus6+"]");

        //Calculating the Hit points
        double hp = (((Math.random()*1000 %6+1)+bonus3)*level);

        //Print the Hit points
        System.out.println("HP : ["+hp+"]");

        //Give the chance to re-roll or continue
        System.out.println("Type r if you want to re-roll or any other character if you want to continue :");
        choice = sc.next();
    }
    while (choice.equals("r"));;

}
```

}

I think i had made mistakes in the second method .I want to figure out how can i use above stored values in the array to calcuate bonus and store the values for bonus in another array.This is the program i have so far.I still didnt got the output i neede.I need to get 6 values from dice roll method and store them in an array.and then i want to call the values to calculate bonus and store those bonus values in another array.

Comment: Can you please paste your complete program?

Comment: The bonus Is a int, your array is named bonusval or val. And you can use util.Random.nextInt (6) + 1 instead of math.random (1000)%6 which  is not divisible by 6 and therefor biased.

Comment: As per my understanding from the problem statement, you can do like this  - "static int[] calculateBonus(int[] val) {" i.e. return the bonus array & take input array as val.

Comment: I posted my whole code i have so far

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like below. I haven't compiled the code, let me know if you face any issues in compiling.

```
static int[] calculateBonus(int[] val) {
   int[] bonusVal = new int[val.length];

   for(int j=0; j < val.length; j++) {
      if (val[j] > 10 && val[j] != 11) {
        bonus[j] = (val[j] - 10) / 2;
      } else if (val[j] < 10) {
        bonus[j] = ((val[j] / 2) - 5);
      } else if (val[j] == 10 || val[j] == 11) {
        bonus[j] = 0;
      }
   }

   return bonusVal;
}
```

Comment: I still getting all 0 as the out put.

Comment: Have you checked your input array - val? what values it contain

Comment: i think i have left one 'i' in the code, have you removed that before compiling your code? Now i have made the edit to code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an array from the first method to start with, right now it doesn't work with an array at all.

Change it to the below to return an array and have a new array variable

```
static int[] diceRoll() { 
  final int rolls = 6;
  int[] result = new int[rolls];

  //the for loop...
```

at the end of the for loop you store the value in the array and then at the end return the array so the end of the method will look like

```
    result[i] = total;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The calculateBonus will use this returned array as input and it will also work internally with an array and not an int as you have now. I also added that it will return an array.

```
static int[] calculateBonus(int[] val){
    int count = val.length;
    int[] bonus = new int[count];

    for(int j=0;j<count;j++) {
        if (val[j] > 10 && val[j] != 11) {
            bonus[j] = (val[j] - 10) / 2;
        } else if (val[j] < 10) {
            bonus[j] = ((val[j] / 2) - 5);
        } else if (val[j] == 10 || val[j] == 11) {
            bonus[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return bonus;
}
```

A simple run

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] values = diceRoll();
  int[] bonus = calculateBonus(values);

  for(int i=0; i<bonus.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(bonus[i]);
  }
}
```

**Update**

Below is a new version of the two methods that addresses the questions I asked in the comment and also clean up the code some.

Main difference is that I use a ArrayList in the diceRole method and that calculateBonus now uses double.

```
static int[] diceRoll() {
  int[] result = new int[6];

  for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      list.add(new Integer((int) ((Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1))));
    }

    Collections.sort(list); //list is now in ascending order

    int total =0;   
    for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
      total += list.get(j).intValue();
    }
    result[i] = total;
  }
  return result;
}

static double[] calculateBonus(int[] val) {
  int count = val.length;
  double[] bonus = new double[count];

  for(int j=0;j<count;j++) {
    double value = 0.0;
    if (val[j] > 11) {
      value = (val[j] - 10.0) / 2.0;
    } else if (val[j] < 10.0) {
      value = ((val[j] / 2.0) - 5.0);
    }
    bonus[j] = value;
  }
  return bonus;
}
```

Comment: Two comments to this code: the method calculateBonus returns an int[], maybe it should works with double[] instead? In the diceRoll() method the situation where two rolls are the same and the lowest isn't handled and total is always 0. Is this intended? Example 2, 2, 3, 4 will add 0 to the result[].

Comment: ok sorry i didnt get what you said.diceRoll method is to roll the dice 4 times and drop the lowest value and get the total.That totals i calculated in the first for loop are the values to 6 variables.And then i have to calculate bonus for those values i got

Comment: Thanks for helping me.I found a way to do now.Thanks again for the ideas